# Creating a checkerboard using Ruby and "\n" not disappearing

Tags: ruby, unicode

I feel as if I am close to a solution and have been tinkering around with this as a newb for some time.  Why, for some reason, are my `"\n"`'s not disappearing when outputted for "next line" and the output has unneeded white space?

**Task:** Write a function which takes one parameter representing the dimensions of a checkered board. The board will always be square, so 5 means you will need a 5x5 board.

The dark squares will be represented by a unicode white square, while the light squares will be represented by a unicode black square (the opposite colors ensure the board doesn't look reversed on code wars' dark background). It should return a string of the board with a space in between each square and taking into account new lines.

An even number should return a board that begins with a dark square. An odd number should return a board that begins with a light square.

The input is expected to be a whole number that's at least two, and returns false otherwise (Nothing in Haskell).

I am close, and here is what I have so far:

```
def checkered_board(dimension)


  black = "\u25A1 "
  white = "\u25A0 "
  checkboard = nil
  checker_array = []
  if dimension < 2 or dimension.is_a? String
    return false
  else 
    count = dimension

    while count <= dimension && count > 0
      if count % 2 == 0
        checkboard = ("\u25A1 \u25A0" + "\n")
        checker_array << checkboard
        count -= 1
      else
        checkboard = ("\u25A0 \u25A1" + "\n")
        checker_array << checkboard
        count -= 1
      end
    end        
  end

  checkboard = checker_array.join(" ")
  p checkboard
end
```

Here is the TDD specs:

```
Test.assert_equals(checkered_board(0), false)
Test.assert_equals(checkered_board(2), "\u25A1 \u25A0\n\u25A0      \u25A1")
```

Note: Hidden specs demonstrate that it should respond with `false` if `dimension` is not an integer.  `.is_a? String` and `.is_a? Integer` is not working for me too.

Output appears like so, and is not appearing even:

```
□ ■
 ■ □
```

Thanks for any and all help :).

Comment: Use `puts` instead of `p` for printing.

Comment: Please state a question explicitly.

Comment: @Mladen Jablanović Thanks, this did help.  However, my output is uneven and curious as to why?  I edited my post to show my output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
if dimension < 2 or dimension.is_a? String
```

to

```
if !dimension.is_a?(Integer) || dimension < 2
```

The left most test will be done first. At the moment, if `dimension` is a `String`, it is first compared with 2 - which will raise an error - before it is tested as to whether it is a `String`. You need to check the type of object before you compare it with another object.

Also, I think the check should be whether `dimension` is not an `Integer`, rather than whether it is a `String`. For example, in your original code, what would happen if dimension was an `Array`?

Comment: Thanks, I tried both ways (`String` and `Integer`) to see them work.  However, now I am curious as to why my output is uneven.  I edited my post to demonstrate my output.

Answer (score 1):

The `join` method will concatenate the elements with a space character inserted between them. So this line from the program:

```
checkboard = checker_array.join(" ")
```

will result in this string:

```
"\u25A1 \u25A0\n \u25A0 \u25A1"
```

Omitting the argument to `join` should produce the expected output, ie.:

```
checkboard = checker_array.join
```

Refer to the documentation on [the Array `join` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join).